# HTML <a> Link href Doesn't Work with "Embedded Spaces" in a "Relative Path"

Tags: html, hyperlink, relative-path

I have searched everywhere I can think of and can't find a single example of an "a" href which contains a relative path on localhost with embedded spaces.
I am trying to download a json file from my localhost located at "json/test file.json". If I rename the file to "json/test-file.json" then the link works fine.  I have hundreds of json files and renaming them will break other applications.
I have also tried putting quotes around 'json/test file.json' and that does not work either.

Here is a simple tag that demonstrates the problem

```
<a id="download_json" href="json/test%20file.json" title="Download JSON" target="new" download>Download</a>
```

I have already tried encodeURI but that is a waste of time.  If you can just hard code the path/file as shown above for testing with nothing fancy it would be helpful and avoid distractions.

This problem must have a very simple solution, I just can't seem to put my finger on it.

Any ideas  will be deeply appreciated, Thank you for your time.

Comment: This *should* work. Are you certain there's not something else about the path that is incorrect?

Comment: It works perfect with a hyphen but not a space.  This is the case with Chrome, Opera, Edge & Firefox.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "doesn't work"? What happens?

Comment: Correction, It works in Chrome, Opera, & Edge but not in Firefox. In Firefox Developers Edition, instead of presenting a "Save As" dialog, the browser clears all panes of the inspector window and the original page remains.  At that point if you try to inspect the page the inspector window is unresponsive until refresh.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally found the answer. Problem only with Firefox Developers Edition

```
function downloadJSON(filename, dataObjToWrite){
  const blob = new Blob([JSON.stringify(dataObjToWrite)], { type: "text/json" });
  const link = document.createElement("a");
  link.download = filename;
  link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  link.dataset.downloadurl = ["text/json", link.download, link.href].join(":");
  const evt = new MouseEvent("click", {
        view: window,
        bubbles: true,
        cancelable: true,
  });
  link.dispatchEvent(evt);
  link.remove()
};
```